# How to: Counting albums and subalbums images and sum images to the main album

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

Table: album

```
album_id  name       parent_album_id
------------------------------------
69        ....       NULL
71        ....       69
72        ....       69
70        ....       NULL
75        ....       NULL
74        ....       NULL
73        ....       NULL
```

Table: album_image

```
album_id      image_id
----------------------
69             256
69             216
69             89
71             896
70             85
```

I want to count all images in the album and if some albums have subalbums then sum that images to the main album.

Like This:

```
album_id        total_images
----------------------------
69              4
70              1
73              0
74              0
75              0
```

Notice that I don't display subalbums (id: 71 and id: 72)

This is the query that I've done, but I doesn't show the correct total images

```
select a.album_id, count(*)
from album a
left join album a2 on a.album_id = a2.parent_album_id
join album_image ai on ai.image_id = IFNULL(a.album_id, a2.album_id)
group by a.album_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is you solution-

```
SELECT IFNULL(a.parent_album_id,a.album_id) AS album_id,sum(result.image_count) as total_images
FROM album a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT album_id,count(image_id) AS image_count FROM album_image GROUP BY album_id) result
ON result.album_id = a.album_id
GROUP BY album_id
```